# Programmatically cancel ROI selection

Tags: matlab

In a GUI, I want to provide several buttons for drawing a ROI of different shape in an image. The user selects the "polygon" button, and when he hovers over the axis, he can draw a polygon-ROI. However, if the user decides to change from polygon to circle (or whatever) **without having drawn a ROI**, the last ROI-draw process has to be canceled. I guess, this reduces to the question, how to programmatically cancel a ROI-drawing process initilalized by, for example, `drawpolygon`.

In the following code, I would like the `drawpolygon`-process to stop if the user clicks the Cancel-button **before** a ROI was drawn. Any ideas? (Note that `drawpolygon` is part of the image processing toolbox and was introduced in Matlab R2018b, thus both are required).

```
function roi2mask()
    [ax, cancel] = local_roi2mask_gui();
    cancel.Callback = @(~,~) display('Cancel was clicked, but how to finish the ROI selection?');
    roi = drawpolygon(ax);
    cancel.Callback = @(~,~) display('ROI was already selected...');
end

function [ax, cancel] = local_roi2mask_gui()
    f = figure('menubar','none','toolbar','none');
    f.Position(3:4) = [300 400];
    p1 = uipanel(f, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0, 0, 1, 2/3], 'Title', 'Axis');

    ax = axes(p1);
    imagesc(ax, peaks(64));

    cancel = uicontrol(f, 'String','Cancel', 'Position', [10, 350, 100, 20]);

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the ROI object, delete it, and call [uiresume](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiresume.html).

Here is an executable code sample:

```
h_fig = figure; %Create a figure, an keep the handle to the figure.
ax = axes(h_fig); %Create an axes in the figure, an keep the handle to the axes.

%Add a button, add set the callback to pb_call.
Button = uicontrol('Parent',h_fig,'Style','pushbutton','String',...
    'Cancel','Units','normalized','Position',[0.8025 0.82 0.1 0.1],'Visible','on',...
    'Tag', 'CancelPushbutton', 'Callback', @pb_call);

roi = drawpolygon(ax, 'Tag', 'MyDrawPolygon'); %Set the tag to 'MyDrawPolygon', so object can be found in pb_call.
if isvalid(roi)
    roi.Tag = ''; %Reset the tag (if not canceled).
end


function pb_call(src, event)
    %Callback function (executed when button is pressed).
    h_fig = src.Parent; %Get handle to the figure (the figure is the parent of the button).
    h_roi = findobj(h_fig, 'Tag', 'MyDrawPolygon'); %Find the Polygon currntly drawn.
    if ~isempty(h_roi)
        h_roi.delete(); %Delete the ROI object.
        uiresume() %Resume execution of blocked program
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I remember a discussion whether the `Tag` property is still useful today. This is such a case!